# Uninstall Spacemacs

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I'm trying to install Emacs via Homebrew. Having done this and aliased to my apps folder, I found that when I ran Emacs it came up Spacemacs. I did them remember the system had Spacemacs installed a few years ago. So, I uninstalled Emacs, removed the emacs folders. Now, Homebrew shows no installation of Emacs. However, when I run emacs in the terminal, I still get Spacemacs.

How do I completely remove Spacemacs so I can install "vanilla" Emacs?

I thought I'd look at where Spacemacs is installed and did a "whereis emacs", but nothing but the prompt was returned.

Comment: check your aliases

Answer (score 22):

Remove or rename `~/emacs.d` folder. Spacemacs is not a different emacs, it's a different way of initializing emacs. The initialization files are in `~/emacs.d`.

Answer (score 3):

I realised that Spacemacs was a layer of Emacs. I needed to delete the .spacemacs folder in my user directory. Once done Emacs showed up as vanilla.

To completely remove emacs, I also searched for "emacs" and it found some folders in various bin directories. Once all of this was removed my system was ready for a vanilla emacs installation.

Answer (score 3):

First, check where your emacs loads its configurations. Probably from `~/.emacs.d`.
Then, remove the folder or just rename it.
Finally, restart emacs
As of spacemacs, there is another file named `.spacemacs`, it usually dwells in your home folder. If you remove/rename `~/.emacs.d` and do nothing about `.spacemacs`,emacs will not read `.spacemacs`.